How to fetch all the API urls from django project in Python?
I have a django project, where some API URLs are present in urls.py in urlpatterns path and some are registered as routers(rest_framework_extensions.routers).
ref:
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path("healthcheck/", health_check_view, name="healthcheck"),
    path("something/", include(router_something.urls))
]

here, router_something is being used to register further urls like:
router_something = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router_something.register(r"path1/(?P<pk>\d+)/roles", SomeViewSet)

I want to fetch all the urls in the django project with their complete path, for example:
healthcheck/
something/path1/1/roles # here i am replacing the placeholder pk with 1, this is something I can do
...


did you test https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/?

Hey @SaeedRamezani, I think it can help with displaying the URLs, but want to do this in code, since I require the URLs dynamically(future API URLs as well).

with the help of these classes you can access to all the urls, but you have to write a recursive algorithm.  from django.urls import URLPattern, URLResolver. It seems you should do something for the routers too.

I found this solution working:
def all_urls():
    """
    Returns all the API routes
    """
    urls = []
    resolver = get_resolver(None)
    for _, v in resolver.reverse_dict.items():
        url_pattern = v and v[1]
        if not url_pattern:
            continue
        url_pattern = re.sub(r"\\(.)", r"\1", url_pattern)
        url_pattern = url_pattern and url_pattern.rstrip("$Z")
        urls.append(url_pattern)
    return list(set(urls))

